# How to Externalise the Tikzpictures while they are already in the document?

Tags: xetex, tikz-external

I have a large (and will be very large) document that takes me very long to compile. I suspect that having few figures that are done with `tikz` takes too long. So what I have done yesterday is to put the following code fragment:

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/] % Where I want the pictures to be output under this folder.
```

and I got an error for unable to find the MD5 of my first figure (created by `tikzpicture`). At few hours of trial-and-error, I managed to get my TeX Studio to compile with making an external user command of

```
"/texlive/bin/win32/xelatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

and it compiles but somehow I got the error of XeLaTeX could not output the pictures into any correct format.

### MWE

(This paragraph is deleted, see the history)

I managed to obtain a MWE that still the error exists. In this MWE, I compiled without the code fragment first. Then input such code and re-compile it again.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/] % Where I want the pictures to be output under this folder.

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
block/.style={%
rectangle,minimum size=6mm,very thick,draw=Tomato!95!Grey!25!
}]
\node (start) [block] {A};
\node (interim) [block,right=of start] {B};
\node (end) [block,right=of interim] {C};
\path (start) edge[->] (interim)
      (interim) edge[->] (end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{some caption}
\label{fig:A}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

An error says:

```
 ! Package tikz Warning: The key 'up to date check=md5' is impossible, there is no macro to compute MD5. Falling back to 'up to date check=diff'.
 ! I can't write on file `figures/main-figure0.md5'.
 <to be read again> 
                    \relax 
 l.53 \end{tikzpicture}

 (Press Enter to retry, or Control-Z to exit; default file extension is `.tex')
 Please type another output file name
 ! Emergency stop.
 <to be read again> 
                    \relax 
 l.53 \end{tikzpicture}

 *** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
```

After I created the directory, from the advice from cfr. Delete the .aux and .auxlock files. It then comes up with an extended warning + error message:

```
! Package tikz Warning: The key 'up to date check=md5' is impossible, there is no macro to compute MD5. Falling back to 'up to date check=diff'.

'xelatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'xelatex -shell-escape -halt-on -error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "figures/PHYSnotes-figure0"  \def\tikzexternalrealjob{PHYSnotes}\input{PHYSnotes}"' ========

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'xelatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "figures/main-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'figures/main-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:.bmp:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'figures/main-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

In addition, I am using

- TeX Live 2016
- Most update TeX Studio portable (I downloaded that two weeks ago)
- XeLaTeX as the compilation method

Comment: There is no problem externalising pictures whose code is included in the document and there is no problem putting the output files into a sub-directory. At least, I don't know about Windows, but it works fine elsewhere. A minimal example would enable people to investigate. Or maybe somebody who uses Windows will happen along. There should be more information on the console output, in the main log file and in the figure-specific log file, but you've not included either that information or code we might use to reproduce the issue. You should, however, try a minimal document with minimal image.

Comment: @cfr MWE added, however there were no .log file generated for the figure specifically.

Comment: That's not an error. The first line is a warning. It isn't clear what the status of the second line is. Does it claim it is an error? Does the externalisation fail? TikZ will be quite explicit about this if it does. I don't see any evidence of an error in what you've posted. The warning is because TikZ cannot find a binary to compute an MD5 sum. So it falls back on another method. So the failure to write the MD5 sum to file is expected, although the information printed could be a bit clearer.

Comment: @cfr My TeX Studio says it is an error. Although the log file says it is a warning.

Comment: Does the sub-directory `figures` exist in your working directory?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Not even the pdf file for the main document

Comment: You need to create the sub-directory first.

Comment: @cfr No hope as well. Situation remains

Comment: @cfr Apologises, the main pdf is generated. Although error message still remains

Comment: Which part of the message remains? Just the stuff about MD5, which is not an error? Take a look in the sub-directory: is the figure's PDF generated there?

Comment: @cfr Yes, the figure has the MD5 now. I created the directory then delete the .aux and .auxlock files and compile again. Error still the same, but with one more (I'll put it in a second)

Comment: @cfr Done editing the log file, it is under the earlier one.

Comment: Presumably you need to call the binary something else or give a full path. See the manual for details. I don't know anything about Windows, sorry.

Comment: @cfr That's the problem, my TeXLive is a portable one. I put this on a thumb drive.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for your assistance. You helped me on developing the question much further.

Comment: Does it want an `.exe` extension? That's the only thing I know about Windows binaries!

Comment: @cfr The message says it couldn't recognised xelatex. Weird since it uses xelatex at first then says so while doing the externalsiation.